# How to get the Primary key of annotate Count

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-annotate

Hi stackoverflow community, my question is about django annotate.

Basically what I am trying to do is to find duplicated value with same values from two different fields in two different tables.

This is my models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    id_order = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

```
class OrderDelivery(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    delivery_address = models.TextField()
```

```
class OrderPickup(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    pickup_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This is my current code:

```
dup_job = Order.objects.filter(
        orderpickup__pickup_date__range=(start_date, end_date)
    ).values(
        'orderdelivery__delivery_address',
        'orderpickup__pickup_date',
    ).annotate(
        duplicated=Count('orderdelivery__delivery_address')
    ).filter(
        duplicated__gt=1
    )
```

Based on what I have, I am getting result like this (delivery_address is omitted for privacy purpose):

```
{'orderdelivery__delivery_address': '118A', 'orderpickup__pickup_date': datetime.date(2022, 3, 9), 'duplicated': 2}
{'orderdelivery__delivery_address': '11', 'orderpickup__pickup_date': datetime.date(2022, 3, 2), 'duplicated': 6}
{'orderdelivery__delivery_address': '11 A ', 'orderpickup__pickup_date': datetime.date(2022, 3, 3), 'duplicated': 5}
{'orderdelivery__delivery_address': '21', 'orderpickup__pickup_date': datetime.date(2022, 3, 10), 'duplicated': 3}
{'orderdelivery__delivery_address': '642', 'orderpickup__pickup_date': datetime.date(2022, 3, 7), 'duplicated': 2}
{'orderdelivery__delivery_address': '642', 'orderpickup__pickup_date': datetime.date(2022, 3, 8), 'duplicated': 2}
{'orderdelivery__delivery_address': 'N/A,5', 'orderpickup__pickup_date': datetime.date(2022, 3, 8), 'duplicated': 19}
```

Is there a way to get the id_order of those 'duplicated'?
I have tried include id_order in .values() but the output will not be accurate as the annotation is grouping by the id_order instead of delivery_address.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the smallest (or largest) item with a [**`Min`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#min) (or `Max`) aggregate:

```
from django.db.models import Min

dup_job = Order.objects.filter(
    orderpickup__pickup_date__range=(start_date, end_date)
).values(
    'orderdelivery__delivery_address',
    'orderpickup__pickup_date',
).annotate(
    min_id_order=Min('id_order')
    duplicated=Count('orderdelivery__delivery_address')
).filter(
    duplicated__gt=1
)
```

or for [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), you can make use of the [**`ArrayAgg`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg) to generate a list:

```
# PostgreSQL only

from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

dup_job = Order.objects.filter(
    orderpickup__pickup_date__range=(start_date, end_date)
).values(
    'orderdelivery__delivery_address',
    'orderpickup__pickup_date',
).annotate(
    min_id_order=ArrayAgg('id_order')
    duplicated=Count('orderdelivery__delivery_address')
).filter(
    duplicated__gt=1
)
```